# How to make usb to shut down Mac Mini

Tags: applescript, usb, mac-mini, shutdown, daemons

I have an old Mac mini and I want to use it as my home server. I don't want to connect any display, keyboard or mouse to it. I will be using it as a wifi router and local server. But I will shut down it sometimes when I go out to keep it safe. Pressing the physical button each time can damage the system, because it is force shutdown. I want to shutdown as usual, but without the mouse,display or keyboard. I think USB is the best solution for it.

I think I need to create something like a daemon or automator that will detect the USB connection and if the usb name is "ShutDown" will call "shut down". Please help me to get it right. I am a developer but I have no experience with AppleScripting.

Comment: As an overview, sounds like you would have a launchd job with a watchpath pointed to /Volumes. From there, you have a script launch that will verify the correct USB drive is inserted. With some kind of audible response, you tell the computer to shutdown. (You can make a second one for restart) This launchd job needs to run as root, to allow the shutdown to happen.

Comment: Why not just enable remote login (either on shell or on UI level) and trigger shutdown that way?

Comment: @ErniePC12 yes you are right. But I don’t know how to do it. A few minutes ago I learned how to load and validate jobs in launchctl and what the syntax of these scripts looks like, but I don't know how to write the correct code for it.

Comment: You should be able to set up ssh and send a remote Terminal shutdown command like `shutdown -h now` for an immediate shutdown, or `shutdown -h 10` for a shutdown in 10 minutes. In Terminal, type `man shutdown` for all the options.

Comment: @nohillside I don't want to open a new macbook every time to turn off this mac mini. It will also be very difficult for my family to shut down it. USB connection is the easiest way for all of us. Just plug in and it turns off.

Comment: @IconDaemon I know how to do it with ssh or screen sharing or other solutions. I need easiest one without any second device:  "Just connect USB and it will turn off"

Comment: Ah, so this is basically "How do I trigger a process when an USB drive is connected" (unless you want to get one of [those](https://drop.com/buy/stack-overflow-the-key-macropad) of course :-))?

Comment: @nohillside if you have one of those so please copy here right full answer for my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really quick and dirty, I haven't had the time to test it. Basically, we run a script when something is mounted. It runs anytime, but we use the script to check for the 1 drive we are looking for. You need to run this under a launchd root job to have permissions to shutdown without entering the password.

The following is the config file for you to install in /Library/LaunchDaemons.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
    <dict>
        <key>PATH</key>
        <string>/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin</string>
    </dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>server.shutdown</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/server_shutdown.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartOnMount</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You need to go into Terminal and run as root the following to load the

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/server.shutdown
```

From here, you create a new script called `server_shutdown.sh` in `/usr/local/bin` and make it executable with `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/server_shutdown.sh`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

DIR="/Volumes/SHUTDOWN/"

if [ -d "$DIR" ]; then
  # Take action if $DIR exists. #
  say "The computer will shut down now."
  #shutdown -h now
fi
```

You could put a check in there for a restart if you wanted. I put in the `say` command to give you an audible message. Just erase the # in front of the shutdown command once you see that the script works.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I‘ve moved the script to /usr/local/bin which seems the better place for this than plain /opt.

Comment: Whichever works. I try to leave my code work out of the OS's directories. Thanks for fixing my mistakes.